# How to clear history in Gedit? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gedit

How do I clear the list of recently opened documents with gedit?

Comment: i tried a lot, could not success..i have downloaded the source code for gedit. there is one clue, but installing it is very hard.

Comment: github.com/GNOME/gedit/tree/master/gedit open it and check for the file gedit-recent.c if you open this file, there is one option called privacy it is set to FALSE, i tried to make it to TRUE and install it, but installing it manually is very hard.

Comment: askubuntu.com/q/407014/739431 if installing is easy, we can make changes into source code and try. but installing is very hard.

Comment: @PRATAP You spent some time on this question and thought you might like to see I posted an answer below.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix sure, will have a look in sometime and revert back to you..

Answer (score 4):

## Permanent method to always set number of entries

I'm revising my answer with a variation of [this GUI answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089134/307523) for command line users.

Use this command to get current number of entries:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents

uint32 5
```

I want to change to `10` so I'll use this command:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents 10

$ gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents

uint32 10
```

If you permanently want to have zero saved recent files change `10` to `0`. Notice how the `get` command is repeated after the `set` command to ensure it "sticks".

## Manual method to remove entries

The `gedit` most recent files list are stored in `USER_DIR/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`.

### Root User

```
$ sudo cat /root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbel version="1.0"
      xmlns:bookmark="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/desktop-bookmarks"
      xmlns:mime="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info"
>
  <bookmark href="file:///etc/default/grub" added="2018-08-03T19:25:50Z" modified="2018-12-27T17:03:38Z" visited="2018-08-03T19:25:51Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="text/plain"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2018-12-27T17:03:38Z" count="41"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
```

### Normal User

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbel version="1.0"
      xmlns:bookmark="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/desktop-bookmarks"
      xmlns:mime="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info"
>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/rick/.conkyrc" added="2019-03-15T10:57:55Z" modified="2019-03-23T19:04:43Z" visited="2019-03-15T10:57:55Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="text/plain"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2019-03-23T19:04:43Z" count="50"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
```

When removing a `gedit` entry delete all lines from `<bookmark href...>` to `</bookmark>` inclusive.

**NOTE:** Other applications store entries in this file, not just `gedit`.

Comment: excellent.. can you please furthermore add the details on how to empty the said lines by running another script so that OP will run that script to clear his gedit history. I have just tried.. the part  `<bookmark href...>` to  `</bookmark>`  but it is not in a single place if multile files are opened other than gedit..

Comment: @Mogli Although a `sed` expert would have a nifty answer, I would simply edit the file and manually delete the lines. Apologies for my sloowwwww comment reply!

Comment: In `vim` to remove `<bookmark href...>` to `</bookmark>` can be used `dat` command  (delete whole tag). Put cursor for example to `bookmark` word and in normal mode enter: `dat`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited:**

In Terminal, type "dconf-editor" to start Configuration Editor. If it is not installed install by

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

To delete search history: Navigate to

> org > gnome > gedit > preferences > ui

change max-recent from 5 to 0.

Comment: Hi, I just tried but couldn't locate the gnome-settings in apps. Photo:https://imgur.com/X7TbFo7

Comment: Hi, edited the answer and tested it. Please try this one. Hope this helps

Comment: Upvoting answer because I used it to increase most recent file list to 10 with: `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents 10`. I found 5 far too few for my needs. I also gave credit to you in my own answer for using `gsettings`. Hope that is ok.

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu 20.04:

Run the following command in terminal:

```
$ dconf-editor
```

Navigate to `/org/gnome/gedit/state/history-entry/search-for-entry` and change `Custom value` to `['']`